# Using Keen.io with CoffeeScript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to use Keen.io, I converted their JS to coffee as follows:

```
# Keen init
Keen = Keen or
  configure: (e) ->
    @_cf = e

  addEvent: (e, t, n, i) ->
    @_eq = @_eq or []
    @_eq.push([e, t, n, i])

  setGlobalProperties: (e) ->
    @_gp = e

  onChartsReady: (e) ->
    @_ocrq = @_ocrq or []
    @_ocrq.push(e)

(->
  e = document.createElement("script")
  e.type = "text/javascript"
  e.async = not 0
  e.src = ((if "https:" is document.location.protocol then "https://" else "http://")) + "dc8na2hxrj29i.cloudfront.net/code/keen-2.1.0-min.js"

  t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
  t.parentNode.insertBefore e, t
)()

Keen.configure myParams

Keen.addEvent "script_tag_init"
```

But looks like events aren't hitting.  What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that would be the problem. The `Keen` object won't be visible to the global scope due to how the CoffeeScript will compile.

"Exporting" `Keen` to window after initializing will work.

Alternatively you can initialize Keen directly on the window object:

```
# Keen init
window.Keen =
  configure: (e) ->
    @_cf = e
  ...
```

Note: This method does exclude checking if `Keen` already exists on the page first, which is a corner-case performance optimization and isn't necessary for most applications. In other words it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since coffee wraps everything in a closure, you need to include this after the call to configure:

```
# Keen works with variable as it is attached to window
window.Keen = Keen
```